# Why does this React App initialize twice?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router, redux-saga

I've build a react app using `webpack`, `react-router`, `redux`, and `redux-saga`.

When I refresh the app initializes twice.

I'm using `websockets` to communicate with a `go` server and have a `saga` that is initialized when the app initializes. 
Because it loads twice - an event that should only fire once, fires twice.

Here's my `index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import Root from './components/Root';
import reducers from './reducers';
import setupSocket from './actionCreators/websocketActions';

import handleNewMessage from './sagas';
import "./styles/main.scss";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, thunk)
);

const { dispatch } = store

const socket = setupSocket(dispatch)

sagaMiddleware.run(handleNewMessage, { socket, user })

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Root />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**How can I prevent this react app from initializing twice on load?**

Comment: what is `user` here?

Comment: It's a util file that generates random names - it shouldn't be in here for simplicity actually. So, I've figured out the double load. It can be prevented by adding "inject: false" into webpack if you're using the "html-webpack-plugin". Only issue is that it changes the styles a little for some reason.

Comment: What does "initialize" mean?

Comment: If you refresh the page the app initializes. I've got a console.log in the index.js and it runs twice.

Comment: I would probably remove this question, as the answer has nothing to do with the code posted

Comment: The saga, "handleNewMessage" was run twice, creating two users when there should only be one. The answer below resolved the issue. It prevents a double initialization.

Answer (score 2):

**I've got it!**

If you are using `html-webpack-plugin`, and `webpack`, make sure you set
`inject: false`:

```
const htmlWebPackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html",
  inject: false,
})
```

I've got a `plugins` section my `webpack.config.dev`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    htmlWebPackPlugin,
    extractSCSS
  ],
};
```

Only odd effect of having this set is that some styles have changed. 
Wondering why that is...

**Styles are resolved by the following in webpack.config:**

```
 {
    test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
    use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
 }
```

Comment: You think that would effect the styles?

Comment: So it looks like the styles are no longer loading after setting inject: false. There must be a way to set up scss with webpack with inject set to false.